# Badge for ????????? tag - I guess the non-ascii characters are converetd to ?'s

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, badges

On Russian.stackexchange.com there is a [badge](https://russian.stackexchange.com/help/badges/87/) that was

> Earned at least 100 total score for at least 20 non-community wiki answers in the ?????????? tag

However there is no such tag on this site. Looks like it is some cyrillic-named tag that was converted to a bunch of question marks.

Comment: @Oded: Status-completed on this post, but not on the original?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - thought Marc did that one. Done now.

Comment: @Oded: I think he didn't yet because he wasn't done yet cleaning up the aftermath. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - that is that. It will take some time for the automated cleanups to finish the job.